# I can't export database using java. Can anyone help me?

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to export a single table (location) from MySQL database (keep) but i can't do it by using java. Please help me.

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("mysqldump –uroot –proot keep location> db_test.sql");
        preparedStatement.execute();
        connection.close();
```

Comment: you can use `Runtime.getRuntime()` .i think that is not a sql query

Comment: **ONLY** SQL queries can be fired through **JDBC/ODBC**. What you are doing is **NOT** SQL.

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: @Ali yasar Erdogan,follow what  'Fast Snail' said.

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump –u root –proot keep location> db_test.sql");` where does it save thanks btw

Comment: @AliyasarErdogan  read this tutorial https://omindu.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/mysql-database-backup-restore-using-java/

Comment: @Ali yasar Erdogan, see my ans below. It's working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single table here is the code. We can save this table to a file.

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "root";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

    String filename = "d:/outfile.sql";
    String tablename = "abc";
    stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE \"" + filename + "\" FROM " + tablename);
```

Comment: Thank you for helps. It worked. Can i use it to create an excel file too?

Comment: I didn't try it. Ill check.

Comment: @Ali yasar Erdogan, link to export a table to excel. https://mikescode.wordpress.com/2008/02/16/exporting-a-mysql-table-to-excel-xls-in-java/

Comment: I just changed `String filenamme = "d:/outfile.xls"` and it worked perfectly.